# How to run the binary with Delve in another folder?

Tags: go, dlv

I want to run Delve in my terminal but I fail to use the correct arguments. It worked a few weeks ago, but I forgot to document the command line.

In VS Code I can run the debugger via:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "run/workdir",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "src",
            "output": "run/workdir/myservicebin"
        }
    ]
}
```

The go.mod/source code is in the src folder. In run/workdir are some setting files for local development. So I want the compiled binary to be run inside run/workdir folder.

I tried:

```bash
cd src
dlv debug --wd ../run/workdir .
```

How to get it running?

Comment: I also asked in the delve GitHub community and as it seems dlv debug --wd ../run/workdir should work and it does work in a sample project. So my guess it that I did a mistake or broke my setup. I will check that at work on Monday and will update here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed up the arguments. I need to use `--output ../run/workdir` instead of `--wd`.